# Complex JPA Specification writing (involving inheritance)

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data, jpa-2.0, spring-data-jpa

I'm fairly new to Spring-Data (mostly worked with Hibernate via HQL until recently) and I'm having trouble wrapping my head around the following :

I have an **AbstractUser** entity, subclassed by **User** and **Admin**. I also have a **Product** entity which has an 1-n relationship with **Project**s. My **User**s are assigned access to specific **Project**s so **User** has a 1-n with **Project**. On the other hand **Admin**s manage entire **Product** lines so **Admin** has a 1-n with **Product**.

Now I'm working on a table showing all users (both **User**s and **Admin**s). I need to be able to filter this by a **specific Project**. This means that for a given **Project**, I need to show all **User**s assigned to it (simple) and all **Admin**s who manage the given **Project**'s parent **Product** (not so simple). I also need this table to be **pageable**.

So I understand that my UserRepository needs to implement JpaSpecificationExecutor and I need to write a Specification in order to call something along the lines of UserRepository.findAll(projectUsersSpecification(projectFilter), pageable) but I have no idea how to go about writing the Specification! I've looked for examples online but nothing I have found covers anything like my specific scenario!

Any help would be most appreciated!

Many thanks,

AW

Here's some code :

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class PersistentEntity implements Serializable {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private Long id;

  ... getter/setter equals & hashcode ...
}

@Entity
@Inheritance
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="TYPE")
@Table(name="User")
public class AbstractUser extends PersistentEntity {

  public enum Profile {
      USER,
      ADMIN;
  }

  @Column
  @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
  private Profile profile;

  ...
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("USER")
public class User extends AbstractUser {

  @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  private List<Project> projects;

}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("ADMIN")
public class Admin extends AbstractUser {

  @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  private List<Product> products;
}

@Entity
@Table
public class Product extends PersistentEntity {

  @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  private List<Project> projects;
}
```

Comment: 1 - Where is AbstractUser declared ? 2 - In an inheritance strategy the super class should be an entity (mapped to database) and not an abstract class.

Comment: Hmm Can't wrap my head around this. If it weren't for the pageable requirement I could just do two separate queries. Maybe my domain model is faulty...

Comment: Are you read some tutorials or examples of using Specifications? I have some experience, so I can help you, but I don't know where the problem is